# Show more text after a <p></p> field

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a script to show more text but in my structure Show more link comes just after the text.

What i want that Show more text must come just at the end of the text. As ı will be using Tinymce to create the text i can not make changes at the text part.

How i can show"... Show More" is on this [image]image

My example is on [Show More Example](http://ptctour.com/show/)

Here is my HTML/JavaScript

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  new ShowMore('example-1', {
    more: ' ... Show more',
    less: ' Show less'
  })

});

//showMore.min.js
var ShowMore = (function() {
  function m(c, a) {
    var d = a.type,
      b = a.more;
    a = a.less;
    this.className = c;
    this.i = d || "span";
    this.more = b;
    this.less = a;
    this.showMore = '<b class="show-more show-more-button same" aria-label="expand" tabindex="0">' + b + "</b>";
    this.showLess = '<b class="show-less show-more-button same" aria-label="collapse" tabindex="0">' + a + "</b>";
    this.regex = {
      c: /[^\x20-\x7E]/gm,
      h: /\s{2,}/gm,
      f: /<\s*\/?br\s*[/]?>/gm
    };
    this.m();
  }
  m.prototype.m = function() {
    for (var c = document.querySelectorAll("." + this.className), a = 0; a < c.length; a++) {
      var d = c[a].getAttribute("data-number"),
        b = c[a].getAttribute("data-after"),
        e = c[a].getAttribute("data-type");
      this.j(e, c[a], +d, +b);
    }
  };
  m.prototype.j = function(c, a, d, b) {
    a.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
    b = d + b;
    if ("text" === c) {
      var e = a.innerHTML;
      var f = e.replace(this.regex.c, "").replace(this.regex.h, " ").replace(this.regex.f, "").length - a.innerText.replace(this.regex.c, "").length;
      a.innerText.length > b &&
        ((f = e
            .replace(this.regex.c, "")
            .replace(this.regex.h, " ")
            .replace(this.regex.f, " ")
            .substr(0, d + f)),
          (f = f.substr(0, Math.min(f.length, f.lastIndexOf(" ")))),
          (a.innerHTML = f),
          this.b({
            type: c,
            element: a,
            l: e,
            o: f
          }));
    }
    if ("list" === c && ((e = [].slice.call(a.children)), e.length > b)) {
      for (f = d; f < e.length; f++) e[f].classList.add("hidden");
      this.b({
        type: c,
        element: a,
        g: d
      });
    }
    if ("table" === c && ((e = a.rows), e.length > b)) {
      for (b = d; b < e.length; b++) e[b].classList.add("hidden");
      this.b({
        type: c,
        element: a,
        g: d
      });
    }
  };
  m.prototype.b = function(c) {
    var a = this,
      d = c.type,
      b = c.element,
      e = c.g,
      f = c.l,
      n = c.o;
    "table" === d ? (b.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", this.showMore), (c = b.nextElementSibling)) : ((c = document.createElement(this.i)), (c.innerHTML = this.showMore), b.appendChild(c), (c = b));
    c.addEventListener("click", function(k) {
      var h = k.currentTarget;
      k = k.target;
      var g = "table" === d ? h.previousElementSibling.getAttribute("aria-expanded") : h.getAttribute("aria-expanded");
      if ("text" === d && k.classList.contains("show-more-button")) {
        b.innerHTML = "";
        b.innerHTML = "false" === g ? f : n;
        var l = document.createElement(a.i);
        l.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "false" === g ? a.showLess : a.showMore);
        "true" === g ? a.a(b, k, a.more, d, !1) : a.a(b, k, a.less, d, !0);
        b.appendChild(l);
      }
      if ("list" === d && k.classList.contains("show-more-button"))
        for (h = [].slice.call(h.children), l = 0; l < h.length; l++)
          "false" === g && (h[l].classList.remove("hidden"), a.a(b, k, a.less, d, !0)), "true" === g && l >= e && l < h.length - 1 && (h[l].classList.add("hidden"), a.a(b, k, a.more, d, !1));
      if ("table" === d)
        if (((h = b.rows), "false" === g)) {
          for (g = 0; g < h.length; g++) h[g].classList.remove("hidden");
          a.a(b, k, a.less, d, !0);
        } else {
          for (g = e; g < h.length; g++) h[g].classList.add("hidden");
          a.a(b, k, a.more, d, !1);
        }
    });
  };
  m.prototype.a = function(c, a, d, b, e) {
    b = "table" === b ? b : "the " + b;
    var f = e ? "collapse" : "expand";
    c.setAttribute("aria-expanded", e);
    a.innerHTML = d;
    a.setAttribute("aria-label", f + " " + b);
  };
  return m;
})();
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <section id="example-text">
    <h2>More text</h2>
    
    <div class="example-1" data-type="text" data-number="500" data-after="1">
      <p><strong>Porque &eacute; que o usamos?</strong></p>
      <p>&Eacute; um facto estabelecido de que um leitor &eacute; distra&iacute;do pelo conte&uacute;do leg&iacute;vel de uma p&aacute;gina quando analisa a sua mancha gr&aacute;fica. Logo, o uso de Lorem Ipsum leva a uma distribui&ccedil;&atilde;o mais
        ou menos normal de letras, ao contr&aacute;rio do uso de "Conte&uacute;do aqui, conte&uacute;do aqui", tornando-o texto leg&iacute;vel. Muitas ferramentas de publica&ccedil;&atilde;o electr&oacute;nica e editores de p&aacute;ginas web usam actualmente
        o Lorem Ipsum como o modelo de texto usado por omiss&atilde;o, e uma pesquisa por "lorem ipsum" ir&aacute; encontrar muitos websites ainda na sua inf&acirc;ncia. V&aacute;rias vers&otilde;es t&ecirc;m evolu&iacute;do ao longo dos anos, por vezes
        por acidente, por vezes propositadamente (como no caso do humor).</p>
      <p><strong>O que &eacute; o Lorem Ipsum?</strong></p>
      <p>O Lorem Ipsum &eacute; um texto modelo da ind&uacute;stria tipogr&aacute;fica e de impress&atilde;o. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto padr&atilde;o usado por estas ind&uacute;strias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma misturou os caracteres de
        um texto para criar um esp&eacute;cime de livro. Este texto n&atilde;o s&oacute; sobreviveu 5 s&eacute;culos, mas tamb&eacute;m o salto para a tipografia electr&oacute;nica, mantendo-se essencialmente inalterada. Foi popularizada nos anos 60 com
        a disponibiliza&ccedil;&atilde;o das folhas de Letraset, que continham passagens com Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente com os programas de publica&ccedil;&atilde;o como o Aldus PageMaker que incluem vers&otilde;es do Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      <p><strong>De onde &eacute; que ele vem?</strong></p>
      <p>Ao contr&aacute;rio da cren&ccedil;a popular, o Lorem Ipsum n&atilde;o &eacute; simplesmente texto aleat&oacute;rio. Tem ra&iacute;zes numa pe&ccedil;a de literatura cl&aacute;ssica em Latim, de 45 AC, tornando-o com mais de 2000 anos. Richard McClintock,
        um professor de Latim no Col&eacute;gio Hampden-Sydney, na Virg&iacute;nia, procurou uma das palavras em Latim mais obscuras (consectetur) numa passagem Lorem Ipsum, e atravessando as cidades do mundo na literatura cl&aacute;ssica, descobriu a
        sua origem. Lorem Ipsum vem das sec&ccedil;&otilde;es 1.10.32 e 1.10.33 do "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (Os Extremos do Bem e do Mal), por C&iacute;cero, escrito a 45AC. Este livro &eacute; um tratado na teoria da &eacute;tica, muito popular
        durante a Renascen&ccedil;a. A primeira linha de Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..." aparece de uma linha na sec&ccedil;&atilde;o 1.10.32.</p>
      <p>O peda&ccedil;o mais habitual do Lorem Ipsum usado desde os anos 1500 &eacute; reproduzido abaixo para os interessados. As sec&ccedil;&otilde;es 1.10.32 e 1.10.33 do "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" do C&iacute;cero tamb&eacute;m est&atilde;o reproduzidos
        na sua forma original, acompanhados pela sua tradu&ccedil;&atilde;o em Ingl&ecirc;s, vers&otilde;es da tradu&ccedil;&atilde;o de 1914 por H. Rackham.</p>
    </div>

  </section>

</div>
```

Comment: A quick fix is to try to set the last p as an inline box `div.example-1 p:last-of-type{display:inline;}` , the best would be to append that link to that last p seen instead inserting it behind ;) demo https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/YzGraQV

Comment: css is just CSS, and your javascript can be rethink while inserting that b tag, tinymce has nothing to do here . since JS creates the button and css uses a selector matching the last p .... one option or the other will work. if the last element is not a p , then just select the last-child. see the demo in codepen with the css rule only https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/YzGraQV

Comment: If you can add below i can choose your answer

Comment: okay, i linked also a pen with sticky for info in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is the idea to turn the last `<p>` to an inline element at screen so the More/less button can stand right behind the text.:

> from earlier comment:
>
> A quick fix is to try to set the last p as an inline box `div.example-1 p:last-of-type{display:inline;}` , the best would be to append that link to that last p seen instead inserting it behind ;) demo https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/YzGraQV  – G-Cyrillus 25 mins ago

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  new ShowMore('example-1', {
    more: ' ... Show more',
    less: ' Show less'
  })

});

//showMore.min.js
var ShowMore = (function() {
  function m(c, a) {
    var d = a.type,
      b = a.more;
    a = a.less;
    this.className = c;
    this.i = d || "span";
    this.more = b;
    this.less = a;
    this.showMore = '<b class="show-more show-more-button same" aria-label="expand" tabindex="0">' + b + "</b>";
    this.showLess = '<b class="show-less show-more-button same" aria-label="collapse" tabindex="0">' + a + "</b>";
    this.regex = {
      c: /[^\x20-\x7E]/gm,
      h: /\s{2,}/gm,
      f: /<\s*\/?br\s*[/]?>/gm
    };
    this.m();
  }
  m.prototype.m = function() {
    for (var c = document.querySelectorAll("." + this.className), a = 0; a < c.length; a++) {
      var d = c[a].getAttribute("data-number"),
        b = c[a].getAttribute("data-after"),
        e = c[a].getAttribute("data-type");
      this.j(e, c[a], +d, +b);
    }
  };
  m.prototype.j = function(c, a, d, b) {
    a.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
    b = d + b;
    if ("text" === c) {
      var e = a.innerHTML;
      var f = e.replace(this.regex.c, "").replace(this.regex.h, " ").replace(this.regex.f, "").length - a.innerText.replace(this.regex.c, "").length;
      a.innerText.length > b &&
        ((f = e
            .replace(this.regex.c, "")
            .replace(this.regex.h, " ")
            .replace(this.regex.f, " ")
            .substr(0, d + f)),
          (f = f.substr(0, Math.min(f.length, f.lastIndexOf(" ")))),
          (a.innerHTML = f),
          this.b({
            type: c,
            element: a,
            l: e,
            o: f
          }));
    }
    if ("list" === c && ((e = [].slice.call(a.children)), e.length > b)) {
      for (f = d; f < e.length; f++) e[f].classList.add("hidden");
      this.b({
        type: c,
        element: a,
        g: d
      });
    }
    if ("table" === c && ((e = a.rows), e.length > b)) {
      for (b = d; b < e.length; b++) e[b].classList.add("hidden");
      this.b({
        type: c,
        element: a,
        g: d
      });
    }
  };
  m.prototype.b = function(c) {
    var a = this,
      d = c.type,
      b = c.element,
      e = c.g,
      f = c.l,
      n = c.o;
    "table" === d ? (b.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", this.showMore), (c = b.nextElementSibling)) : ((c = document.createElement(this.i)), (c.innerHTML = this.showMore), b.appendChild(c), (c = b));
    c.addEventListener("click", function(k) {
      var h = k.currentTarget;
      k = k.target;
      var g = "table" === d ? h.previousElementSibling.getAttribute("aria-expanded") : h.getAttribute("aria-expanded");
      if ("text" === d && k.classList.contains("show-more-button")) {
        b.innerHTML = "";
        b.innerHTML = "false" === g ? f : n;
        var l = document.createElement(a.i);
        l.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "false" === g ? a.showLess : a.showMore);
        "true" === g ? a.a(b, k, a.more, d, !1) : a.a(b, k, a.less, d, !0);
        b.appendChild(l);
      }
      if ("list" === d && k.classList.contains("show-more-button"))
        for (h = [].slice.call(h.children), l = 0; l < h.length; l++)
          "false" === g && (h[l].classList.remove("hidden"), a.a(b, k, a.less, d, !0)), "true" === g && l >= e && l < h.length - 1 && (h[l].classList.add("hidden"), a.a(b, k, a.more, d, !1));
      if ("table" === d)
        if (((h = b.rows), "false" === g)) {
          for (g = 0; g < h.length; g++) h[g].classList.remove("hidden");
          a.a(b, k, a.less, d, !0);
        } else {
          for (g = e; g < h.length; g++) h[g].classList.add("hidden");
          a.a(b, k, a.more, d, !1);
        }
    });
  };
  m.prototype.a = function(c, a, d, b, e) {
    b = "table" === b ? b : "the " + b;
    var f = e ? "collapse" : "expand";
    c.setAttribute("aria-expanded", e);
    a.innerHTML = d;
    a.setAttribute("aria-label", f + " " + b);
  };
  return m;
})();
```

```css
div.example-1 p:last-of-type {
  display: inline;
}

b {
  color: #0095E5
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <section id="example-text">
    <h2>More text</h2>

    <div class="example-1" data-type="text" data-number="500" data-after="1">
      <p><strong>Porque &eacute; que o usamos?</strong></p>
      <p>&Eacute; um facto estabelecido de que um leitor &eacute; distra&iacute;do pelo conte&uacute;do leg&iacute;vel de uma p&aacute;gina quando analisa a sua mancha gr&aacute;fica. Logo, o uso de Lorem Ipsum leva a uma distribui&ccedil;&atilde;o mais
        ou menos normal de letras, ao contr&aacute;rio do uso de "Conte&uacute;do aqui, conte&uacute;do aqui", tornando-o texto leg&iacute;vel. Muitas ferramentas de publica&ccedil;&atilde;o electr&oacute;nica e editores de p&aacute;ginas web usam actualmente
        o Lorem Ipsum como o modelo de texto usado por omiss&atilde;o, e uma pesquisa por "lorem ipsum" ir&aacute; encontrar muitos websites ainda na sua inf&acirc;ncia. V&aacute;rias vers&otilde;es t&ecirc;m evolu&iacute;do ao longo dos anos, por vezes
        por acidente, por vezes propositadamente (como no caso do humor).</p>
      <p><strong>O que &eacute; o Lorem Ipsum?</strong></p>
      <p>O Lorem Ipsum &eacute; um texto modelo da ind&uacute;stria tipogr&aacute;fica e de impress&atilde;o. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto padr&atilde;o usado por estas ind&uacute;strias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma misturou os caracteres de
        um texto para criar um esp&eacute;cime de livro. Este texto n&atilde;o s&oacute; sobreviveu 5 s&eacute;culos, mas tamb&eacute;m o salto para a tipografia electr&oacute;nica, mantendo-se essencialmente inalterada. Foi popularizada nos anos 60 com
        a disponibiliza&ccedil;&atilde;o das folhas de Letraset, que continham passagens com Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente com os programas de publica&ccedil;&atilde;o como o Aldus PageMaker que incluem vers&otilde;es do Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      <p><strong>De onde &eacute; que ele vem?</strong></p>
      <p>Ao contr&aacute;rio da cren&ccedil;a popular, o Lorem Ipsum n&atilde;o &eacute; simplesmente texto aleat&oacute;rio. Tem ra&iacute;zes numa pe&ccedil;a de literatura cl&aacute;ssica em Latim, de 45 AC, tornando-o com mais de 2000 anos. Richard McClintock,
        um professor de Latim no Col&eacute;gio Hampden-Sydney, na Virg&iacute;nia, procurou uma das palavras em Latim mais obscuras (consectetur) numa passagem Lorem Ipsum, e atravessando as cidades do mundo na literatura cl&aacute;ssica, descobriu a
        sua origem. Lorem Ipsum vem das sec&ccedil;&otilde;es 1.10.32 e 1.10.33 do "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (Os Extremos do Bem e do Mal), por C&iacute;cero, escrito a 45AC. Este livro &eacute; um tratado na teoria da &eacute;tica, muito popular
        durante a Renascen&ccedil;a. A primeira linha de Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..." aparece de uma linha na sec&ccedil;&atilde;o 1.10.32.</p>
      <p>O peda&ccedil;o mais habitual do Lorem Ipsum usado desde os anos 1500 &eacute; reproduzido abaixo para os interessados. As sec&ccedil;&otilde;es 1.10.32 e 1.10.33 do "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" do C&iacute;cero tamb&eacute;m est&atilde;o reproduzidos
        na sua forma original, acompanhados pela sua tradu&ccedil;&atilde;o em Ingl&ecirc;s, vers&otilde;es da tradu&ccedil;&atilde;o de 1914 por H. Rackham.</p>
    </div>

  </section>

</div>
```

or play with position :https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/JjRrLvR it sets it on the far right at bottom.

Answer (score 1):

I am using a quick positioning fix to do this. Setting parent `div` as `position:relative;` and then `span` element `position:absolute;`.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  new ShowMore('example-1', {
    more: ' ... Show more',
    less: ' Show less'
  })

});

//showMore.min.js
var ShowMore = (function() {
  function m(c, a) {
    var d = a.type,
      b = a.more;
    a = a.less;
    this.className = c;
    this.i = d || "span";
    this.more = b;
    this.less = a;
    this.showMore = '<b class="show-more show-more-button same" aria-label="expand" tabindex="0" style="position: absolute;bottom: 0;right: 0;">' + b + "</b>";
    this.showLess = '<b class="show-less show-more-button same" aria-label="collapse" tabindex="0">' + a + "</b>";
    this.regex = {
      c: /[^\x20-\x7E]/gm,
      h: /\s{2,}/gm,
      f: /<\s*\/?br\s*[/]?>/gm
    };
    this.m();
  }
  m.prototype.m = function() {
    for (var c = document.querySelectorAll("." + this.className), a = 0; a < c.length; a++) {
      var d = c[a].getAttribute("data-number"),
        b = c[a].getAttribute("data-after"),
        e = c[a].getAttribute("data-type");
      this.j(e, c[a], +d, +b);
    }
  };
  m.prototype.j = function(c, a, d, b) {
    a.setAttribute("aria-expanded", "false");
    a.style.position = 'relative';
    b = d + b;
    if ("text" === c) {
      var e = a.innerHTML;
      var f = e.replace(this.regex.c, "").replace(this.regex.h, " ").replace(this.regex.f, "").length - a.innerText.replace(this.regex.c, "").length;
      a.innerText.length > b &&
        ((f = e
            .replace(this.regex.c, "")
            .replace(this.regex.h, " ")
            .replace(this.regex.f, " ")
            .substr(0, d + f)),
          (f = f.substr(0, Math.min(f.length, f.lastIndexOf(" ")))),
          (a.innerHTML = f),
          this.b({
            type: c,
            element: a,
            l: e,
            o: f
          }));
    }
    if ("list" === c && ((e = [].slice.call(a.children)), e.length > b)) {
      for (f = d; f < e.length; f++) e[f].classList.add("hidden");
      this.b({
        type: c,
        element: a,
        g: d
      });
    }
    if ("table" === c && ((e = a.rows), e.length > b)) {
      for (b = d; b < e.length; b++) e[b].classList.add("hidden");
      this.b({
        type: c,
        element: a,
        g: d
      });
    }
  };
  m.prototype.b = function(c) {
    var a = this,
      d = c.type,
      b = c.element,
      e = c.g,
      f = c.l,
      n = c.o;
    "table" === d ? (b.insertAdjacentHTML("afterend", this.showMore), (c = b.nextElementSibling)) : ((c = document.createElement(this.i)), (c.innerHTML = this.showMore), b.appendChild(c), (c = b));
    c.addEventListener("click", function(k) {
      var h = k.currentTarget;
      k = k.target;
      var g = "table" === d ? h.previousElementSibling.getAttribute("aria-expanded") : h.getAttribute("aria-expanded");
      if ("text" === d && k.classList.contains("show-more-button")) {
        b.innerHTML = "";
        b.innerHTML = "false" === g ? f : n;
        var l = document.createElement(a.i);
        l.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", "false" === g ? a.showLess : a.showMore);
        "true" === g ? a.a(b, k, a.more, d, !1) : a.a(b, k, a.less, d, !0);
        b.appendChild(l);
      }
      if ("list" === d && k.classList.contains("show-more-button"))
        for (h = [].slice.call(h.children), l = 0; l < h.length; l++)
          "false" === g && (h[l].classList.remove("hidden"), a.a(b, k, a.less, d, !0)), "true" === g && l >= e && l < h.length - 1 && (h[l].classList.add("hidden"), a.a(b, k, a.more, d, !1));
      if ("table" === d)
        if (((h = b.rows), "false" === g)) {
          for (g = 0; g < h.length; g++) h[g].classList.remove("hidden");
          a.a(b, k, a.less, d, !0);
        } else {
          for (g = e; g < h.length; g++) h[g].classList.add("hidden");
          a.a(b, k, a.more, d, !1);
        }
    });
  };
  m.prototype.a = function(c, a, d, b, e) {
    b = "table" === b ? b : "the " + b;
    var f = e ? "collapse" : "expand";
    c.setAttribute("aria-expanded", e);
    a.innerHTML = d;
    a.setAttribute("aria-label", f + " " + b);
  };
  return m;
})();
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <section id="example-text">
    <h2>More text</h2>
    
    <div class="example-1" data-type="text" data-number="500" data-after="1">
      <p><strong>Porque &eacute; que o usamos?</strong></p>
      <p>&Eacute; um facto estabelecido de que um leitor &eacute; distra&iacute;do pelo conte&uacute;do leg&iacute;vel de uma p&aacute;gina quando analisa a sua mancha gr&aacute;fica. Logo, o uso de Lorem Ipsum leva a uma distribui&ccedil;&atilde;o mais
        ou menos normal de letras, ao contr&aacute;rio do uso de "Conte&uacute;do aqui, conte&uacute;do aqui", tornando-o texto leg&iacute;vel. Muitas ferramentas de publica&ccedil;&atilde;o electr&oacute;nica e editores de p&aacute;ginas web usam actualmente
        o Lorem Ipsum como o modelo de texto usado por omiss&atilde;o, e uma pesquisa por "lorem ipsum" ir&aacute; encontrar muitos websites ainda na sua inf&acirc;ncia. V&aacute;rias vers&otilde;es t&ecirc;m evolu&iacute;do ao longo dos anos, por vezes
        por acidente, por vezes propositadamente (como no caso do humor).</p>
      <p><strong>O que &eacute; o Lorem Ipsum?</strong></p>
      <p>O Lorem Ipsum &eacute; um texto modelo da ind&uacute;stria tipogr&aacute;fica e de impress&atilde;o. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto padr&atilde;o usado por estas ind&uacute;strias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma misturou os caracteres de
        um texto para criar um esp&eacute;cime de livro. Este texto n&atilde;o s&oacute; sobreviveu 5 s&eacute;culos, mas tamb&eacute;m o salto para a tipografia electr&oacute;nica, mantendo-se essencialmente inalterada. Foi popularizada nos anos 60 com
        a disponibiliza&ccedil;&atilde;o das folhas de Letraset, que continham passagens com Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente com os programas de publica&ccedil;&atilde;o como o Aldus PageMaker que incluem vers&otilde;es do Lorem Ipsum.</p>
      <p><strong>De onde &eacute; que ele vem?</strong></p>
      <p>Ao contr&aacute;rio da cren&ccedil;a popular, o Lorem Ipsum n&atilde;o &eacute; simplesmente texto aleat&oacute;rio. Tem ra&iacute;zes numa pe&ccedil;a de literatura cl&aacute;ssica em Latim, de 45 AC, tornando-o com mais de 2000 anos. Richard McClintock,
        um professor de Latim no Col&eacute;gio Hampden-Sydney, na Virg&iacute;nia, procurou uma das palavras em Latim mais obscuras (consectetur) numa passagem Lorem Ipsum, e atravessando as cidades do mundo na literatura cl&aacute;ssica, descobriu a
        sua origem. Lorem Ipsum vem das sec&ccedil;&otilde;es 1.10.32 e 1.10.33 do "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (Os Extremos do Bem e do Mal), por C&iacute;cero, escrito a 45AC. Este livro &eacute; um tratado na teoria da &eacute;tica, muito popular
        durante a Renascen&ccedil;a. A primeira linha de Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..." aparece de uma linha na sec&ccedil;&atilde;o 1.10.32.</p>
      <p>O peda&ccedil;o mais habitual do Lorem Ipsum usado desde os anos 1500 &eacute; reproduzido abaixo para os interessados. As sec&ccedil;&otilde;es 1.10.32 e 1.10.33 do "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" do C&iacute;cero tamb&eacute;m est&atilde;o reproduzidos
        na sua forma original, acompanhados pela sua tradu&ccedil;&atilde;o em Ingl&ecirc;s, vers&otilde;es da tradu&ccedil;&atilde;o de 1914 por H. Rackham.</p>
    </div>

  </section>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A very quick fix would be as follows:

```
.example-1{
   position:relative;
}

.example-1 span{
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

There is even more quicker solution:

```
.example-1 p:nth-child(2){
   display:inline;
}
```

Comment: it might stand over the text ;) , look at sticky and float to the right maybe

Comment: This was what i did in my answer, but i dit it in the js

Comment: I didn't saw it my Friend. Shall I delete my answer :) Or keep it. Whatever you wish :)

Comment: I just say, to show that maybe its the best way, becouse we both think the same thing.

You can keep it, i think is simple.

Comment: You are a nice person. I am voting your answer. I like sincere guys and I also help anyone who is sincere. :)

Comment: @Sena: Where is your CSS code :) Did I updated your answer in the best way :) If not you make edit as per your code changes, One advise: Don't mention "you code is not a good one" :)

Comment: Thanks, I'll remember that.

Comment: GOD BELSS YOU FRIEND :) I voted for you, your code is spot on :)

Comment: .example-1 p:nth-child(2){
   display:inline;
} this works also

Comment: @JamesDean : Use whatever best suites you My Friend :) Sometimes there are many ways to solve the particular problem. Do vote and ratet if this has helped you in any way or form. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

the `p` tag is a block display element that's why the "show more" starts at new line, try changing it to `span`, I tried it on developer tools and it worked.

```
<div class="container">

  <section id="example-text">
    <h2>More text</h2>
    
    <div class="example-1" data-type="text" data-number="500" data-after="1">
      <p><strong>Porque &eacute; que o usamos?</strong></p>
      <span>&Eacute; um facto estabelecido de que um leitor &eacute; distra&iacute;do pelo conte&uacute;do leg&iacute;vel de uma p&aacute;gina quando analisa a sua mancha gr&aacute;fica. Logo, o uso de Lorem Ipsum leva a uma distribui&ccedil;&atilde;o mais
        ou menos normal de letras, ao contr&aacute;rio do uso de "Conte&uacute;do aqui, conte&uacute;do aqui", tornando-o texto leg&iacute;vel. Muitas ferramentas de publica&ccedil;&atilde;o electr&oacute;nica e editores de p&aacute;ginas web usam actualmente
        o Lorem Ipsum como o modelo de texto usado por omiss&atilde;o, e uma pesquisa por "lorem ipsum" ir&aacute; encontrar muitos websites ainda na sua inf&acirc;ncia. V&aacute;rias vers&otilde;es t&ecirc;m evolu&iacute;do ao longo dos anos, por vezes
        por acidente, por vezes propositadamente (como no caso do humor).</span>
      <p><strong>O que &eacute; o Lorem Ipsum?</strong></p>
      <span>O Lorem Ipsum &eacute; um texto modelo da ind&uacute;stria tipogr&aacute;fica e de impress&atilde;o. O Lorem Ipsum tem vindo a ser o texto padr&atilde;o usado por estas ind&uacute;strias desde o ano de 1500, quando uma misturou os caracteres de
        um texto para criar um esp&eacute;cime de livro. Este texto n&atilde;o s&oacute; sobreviveu 5 s&eacute;culos, mas tamb&eacute;m o salto para a tipografia electr&oacute;nica, mantendo-se essencialmente inalterada. Foi popularizada nos anos 60 com
        a disponibiliza&ccedil;&atilde;o das folhas de Letraset, que continham passagens com Lorem Ipsum, e mais recentemente com os programas de publica&ccedil;&atilde;o como o Aldus PageMaker que incluem vers&otilde;es do Lorem Ipsum.</span>
      <p><strong>De onde &eacute; que ele vem?</strong></p>
      <span>Ao contr&aacute;rio da cren&ccedil;a popular, o Lorem Ipsum n&atilde;o &eacute; simplesmente texto aleat&oacute;rio. Tem ra&iacute;zes numa pe&ccedil;a de literatura cl&aacute;ssica em Latim, de 45 AC, tornando-o com mais de 2000 anos. Richard McClintock,
        um professor de Latim no Col&eacute;gio Hampden-Sydney, na Virg&iacute;nia, procurou uma das palavras em Latim mais obscuras (consectetur) numa passagem Lorem Ipsum, e atravessando as cidades do mundo na literatura cl&aacute;ssica, descobriu a
        sua origem. Lorem Ipsum vem das sec&ccedil;&otilde;es 1.10.32 e 1.10.33 do "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" (Os Extremos do Bem e do Mal), por C&iacute;cero, escrito a 45AC. Este livro &eacute; um tratado na teoria da &eacute;tica, muito popular
        durante a Renascen&ccedil;a. A primeira linha de Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..." aparece de uma linha na sec&ccedil;&atilde;o 1.10.32.</span>
      <span>O peda&ccedil;o mais habitual do Lorem Ipsum usado desde os anos 1500 &eacute; reproduzido abaixo para os interessados. As sec&ccedil;&otilde;es 1.10.32 e 1.10.33 do "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" do C&iacute;cero tamb&eacute;m est&atilde;o reproduzidos
        na sua forma original, acompanhados pela sua tradu&ccedil;&atilde;o em Ingl&ecirc;s, vers&otilde;es da tradu&ccedil;&atilde;o de 1914 por H. Rackham.</span>
    </div>

  </section>

</div>
```

Hope this would solve the problem.

Comment: As we create texts by using tinymce editor. we can not change p tag to span.

Comment: oh sorry for my misunderstand, maybe try this if possible to add a class to the `p` add this style: `display: inline;` or this if not `section#example-text p {
    display: inline;
}`

Comment: @SohilaKhaled : Yes, display:inline; on last <p> tag does work.  .                     
 example-1 p:nth-child(2){
   display:inline;
}