# How i can move Readmore link In html and Css After a paragraph text

Tags: html, css, sass

Any one can help me how to posision a Readmore link Like on the picture using Css and Html

Here is the code

```html
<div class="post-content">
  <div class="inner-contne">
    <p>Proin eget tortor risus. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Proin eget tortor risus. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet
      et, porttitor at sem.</p>
  </div>

  <a>Read MORE</a></div>
```

[image]

Comment: probably a duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65424975/show-more-text-after-a-p-p-field

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Show more text after a <p></p> field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65424975/show-more-text-after-a-p-p-field)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with the `<span>` element. Its like a `<div>` but a `<div>` element is a block element and `<span>` is an inline element

```html
<div class="post-content">
  <div class="inner-contne">
    <p>Proin eget tortor risus. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Proin eget tortor risus. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet
      et, porttitor at sem.<span><a>Read MORE</a></span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `p` to display `inline`. Currently the paragraph takes up the whole row.

```
p {
   display: inline;
}
```

Comment: there also a div wrapping the p in the way ;)

Comment: Place the link inside ```inner-content```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="post-content">
  <div class="inner-contne">
    <p>Proin eget tortor risus. Nulla porttitor accumsan tincidunt. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Mauris blandit aliquet elit, eget tincidunt nibh pulvinar a. Proin eget tortor risus. Curabitur arcu erat, accumsan id imperdiet
      et, porttitor at sem.  <a>Read MORE</a></p>
  </div>
 </div>
```